# Problem after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

After upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 when I boot into ubuntu I can see a black screen asking for a username and password,when I entered all these details it shows welcome to ubuntu 16.04 and all those. But still I am not able to see the desktop. It still in the position of accept commands from me as in the terminal we used to get

[image]

Comment: If you are using a proprietary video driver, you need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: And the kernel version is wrong. It looks like the upgrade is not complete.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/804755/how-can-i-get-kubuntu-desktop-to-come-up/804872#804872) of any help?